# Single particle tunneling Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, quantum-tunneling

In reference to Problem 9, Chapter 2 in [Modern Quantum Mechanics by JJ Sakurai](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=JCS-S1tLx7MC&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=modern%20quantum%20mechanics%20sakurai%20tunneling%20effect%20is&source=bl&ots=3pwODHKvHY&sig=9yWKM4ZSWwoHZs14fwvxaE6J5uQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM6d6a0YHMAhWQxY4KHTDvCt8Q6AEIMTAD#v=onepage&q=modern%20quantum%20mechanics%20sakurai%20tunneling%20effect%20is&f=false),

For a single particle tunneling in a 1D double well potential, with position eigenkets $\mid R\rangle$, $\mid L\rangle$. A general state can be written as:
$$
\mid \alpha \rangle=\mid R\rangle\langle R\mid\alpha\rangle + \mid L\rangle\langle L\mid\alpha\rangle
$$
The particle can tunnel through the barrier and it says that this tunneling effect can be characterized by the Hamiltonian:
$$
H=\Delta\bigg(\mid L\rangle\langle R\mid+\mid R\rangle\langle L\mid\bigg)
$$

With the given information the problem can be easily solved as 
$$
\Delta=+E\\
\mid E+\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(\mid R\rangle+\mid L\rangle\big)
$$
and
$$
\Delta=-E\\
\mid E-\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(\mid R\rangle-\mid L\rangle\big)
$$

But how do we came to know the form of the Hamiltonian for tunneling is the one given above in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply the most general kind of interaction Hamiltonian you can write down in this simplified two-level system. On the 2D Hilbert space spanned by $\lvert R\rangle,\lvert L \rangle$, the most general linear operator is written as
$$ A = a_\text{RR}\lvert R\rangle\langle R\rvert + a_\text{RL}\lvert R\rangle\langle L \rvert + a_\text{LR}\lvert L\rangle\langle R\rvert + a_\text{LL}\lvert L\rangle\langle L\rvert$$
and the first and the last term do not describe an interaction, so we drop them. Self-adjointness of the Hamiltonian also forces $a_\text{RL} = a_\text{LR}^\ast$, and choosing them real, we are left with one free parameter, namely $\Delta = a_\text{RL} = a_\text{LR}$.

Comment: how can we say the first and last term do not describe an interaction, srry do not understand it. And how do you know $a_{RL}=a_{LR}$ ?

Comment: and how do we write if we have two particles in the double well ?. I think in that case there will be a 4D Hilbert space spanned by $\mid LL\rangle, \mid LR\rangle, \mid RL\rangle, \mid RR\rangle$

Comment: @ss1729: The first and the last term just send a state to itself, that's not an interaction. And I wrote how I know $a_\text{RL} = a_\text{LR}$ - the Hamiltonian has to be self-adjoint.